# select options disappear after open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hogan.js

After click on select options are show just in second and after user can't choose option for wizard.

We using Hogan.js and bootstrap and on other elements work great but on one specific modal its not working, on other modals working also great.

```
<select name="date-range" class="form-control">
  <option value="week-over-week">Week Over Week</option>
  <option value="month-over-month">Month Over Month</option>
  <option value="quarter-over-quarter">Quarter Over Quarter</option>
  <option value="year-over-year">Year Over Year</option>
  <option value="false">-------------</option>
  <option value="custom">Custom Date Range</option>
```

UPDATE: We found that maybe is problem when calling div over modal container and inside  div we have select option, also this happen only in FF.

UPDATE: Select option is inside `ul` tag and look like

`<ul class="dropdown-menu hasdaterange" role="menu"                      style="position:    absolute; top: 175px; left: 803px;">
   <li>
     <div class="calendar"><select>..</select>
   </li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have dropdown in dropdown in modal. Try to re-factor yours html elements.